# Why am I getting a foreign key conflict when creating migrations for my reservation class in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm building out a reservation system in ASP.NET Core 6 MVC. When I create my reservation class however and go to make my migrations I am getting this error:

> The foreign key property 'Reservation.ClientID1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'ClientID' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-relationships for information on mapping relationships in EF Core.

I am following the same practices as I have done throughout with no issue. Was hoping someone could help me out. I am getting this for all 5 of the foreign keys I am trying to create.

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ReservationNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ReservedPax { get; set; }
    public int Comps { get; set; }
    public int? ActualPax { get; set; }
    public string SpecialRequests { get; set; }
    public string AlcoholRequests { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }

    public int MenuID { get; set; }
    public virtual Menu Menu { get; set; }

    public int StatusID { get; set; }
    public virtual Status Status { get; set; }

    public int ContactID { get; set; }
    public virtual Contact Contact { get; set; }


    public int RestaurantID { get; set; }
    public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }

    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ReservationMenuItem> ReservationMenuItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<ReservationMenuItem>();
```

---

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Contact)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ContactID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Menu)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.MenuID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Status)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.StatusID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Client)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.ClientID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

        modelBuilder.Entity<Reservation>()
            .HasOne(r => r.Restaurant)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(r => r.RestaurantID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```

I've tried altering the context with being more specific but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think there was an error during your migrations, delete them and your DB then try again....

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).